# Cannot send form with file to .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, forms, webapi

I am trying to send an XML file to my ASP.NET Core API, but it is not working.

I have the following action in my API controller:

```cs
[HttpPost("{xml=false}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<SubscriberModel>> PostSubscriberModel(bool xml, [FromForm]IFormFile uploadFile, SubscriberModel subscriberModel)
        {
            List<SubscriberModel> subscriberList;


            if (uploadFile is not null && xml)
            {
                if (uploadFile.Length > 0)
                {

                    XmlSerializer serializer = new(typeof(List<SubscriberModel>));

                    subscriberList = serializer.Deserialize(uploadFile.OpenReadStream()) as List<SubscriberModel>;

                    _context.Subscribers.AddRange(subscriberList);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return Ok();
                }
                return BadRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                _context.Subscribers.Add(subscriberModel);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return CreatedAtAction("GetSubscriberModel", new { id = subscriberModel.Su_Id }, subscriberModel);
            }
        }
```

And on my frontend I have this form:

```
<form method="post" action="https://localhost:7044/api/subscriber?xml=true" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label class="form-label">Upload file with subscribers (.xml)</label>
      <input class="form-control" accept="text/xml" type="file" name="uploadFile">
    
      <input class="btn-primary btn" type="submit"/>
  </form>
```

However, when choose a file and submit the form I get a 415 (Unsupported Media Type) in the browser.

```
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"00-4eb7ff4a9bb2a8c115c78e919bac7512-a03a80991a7b8c55-00"}
```

When a breakpoint is set on the action, it is never triggered. Also, the web server does not throw any errors.
Why is this? I feel like both the method signature on the action and the form is correct? Have I missed something obvious?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can't you just create a model with a file in it and then as parameter [FromForm] Model model. [example](https://makolyte.com/aspnetcore-receive-a-file-in-the-request/)